# Simple caching in Java using hashmap

Tags: java, caching, hashmap

Just want to use java hashmap to cache a simple  pair into memory and want to get the cached data in another instance.

I am using the below code to put some datas into cache consider the below ProcessDefinitionJavaCode.java code.

```
package Folder.ProcessDefinition;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ProcessDefinitionJavaCode{
/****** START SET/GET METHOD, DO NOT MODIFY *****/
    protected String string_1 = "";
    protected String string_2 = "";
    public String getstring_1() {
        return string_1;
    }
    public void setstring_1(String val) {
        string_1 = val;
    }
    public String getstring_2() {
        return string_2;
    }
    public void setstring_2(String val) {
        string_2 = val;
    }
/****** END SET/GET METHOD, DO NOT MODIFY *****/
    public ProcessDefinitionJavaCode() {
    }
    public void invoke() throws Exception {
/* Available Variables: DO NOT MODIFY
    In  : String string_1
    In  : String string_2
* Available Variables: DO NOT MODIFY *****/

HashMap<Integer,String> cache = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
cache.put(21, "Twenty One");
cache.put(31, "Thirty One");

}
}
```

What should I be doing If I want to get the datas I added just now in cache 
in another java class temp.java.
I am sorry if it is very silly, I am not a Java expert..

Comment: Just need a solution to put some values into cache and retrieve the same ..

Comment: This seems very dodgy, but ile try and add my 2 cents not knowing the full scope to the problem. Firstly use this: 
public static ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();

You should typically write some convenience methods to prevent direct access to the cache, but you can use ProcessDefinitionJavaCode.cache for direct access from your other objects, but I would not advise this and I would also not advise passing it around as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the cache Hashmap to the other class in a constructor or a setter method.

```
HashMap<Integer,String> cache = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
cache.put(21, "Twenty One");
cache.put(31, "Thirty One");

NewClass newClass = new newClass(cache);

or

NewClass newClass = new newClass();
newClass.setCache(cache);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only method I know to retrieve the values from a map is creating a function to do so.

That way you can create a function like this:

```
String[] getValues(){
     String[] aux=new String[cache.size()];
     int i=0;
     for (Integer integer : cache.keySet()) {
        aux[i++]=cache.get(integer);
     }

     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aux));
     return aux;
}
```

Comment: Actually want to get the value I just added in cache in another java class

Comment: That will be more complicated because the HashMap doesn't save the values sequentially... the only solution I can find is you save the last value added in a variable.

Comment: You can use `LinkedHashMap` for iterating over `key-value` pairs in order of addition.

Comment: @Manuel Pires.. I will make it more simple.. I just want to get the hasmap values I added in the above in another .java file.. sorry if I am being clear

Comment: @AbdulKader I edited the answer... this is the only method I know to get the values of a HashMap.

Comment: Or you could simply get all the values by using cache.values() which would return a collection.

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple approach (it may be not exactly what you want, but you may get an useful idea):

```
class PairOfStrings {
    final String a, b;

    PairOfStrings(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PairOfStrings{" +
                "a='" + a + '\'' +
                ", b='" + b + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, PairOfStrings> pairs = new HashMap<Integer, PairOfStrings>();
        pairs.put(1, new PairOfStrings("first", "second"));
        pairs.put(2, new PairOfStrings("third", "fourth"));
        System.out.println(pairs.get(1));
    }
}
```